# How to substitute libedit readline with GNU readline on Mac OS

Tags: macos, gnu, readline, netbsd

On my Mac OS (Moneterey 12.1) I see $NetBSD: readline.h, v 1.33 2012/05/15  which I guess is a part of libedit library. I want to use readline.h which is a part of GNU readline library.
Is it possible to do that? And what steps should I implement?
May be I use some incorrect terminology or misunderstand some concepts. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. I myself have an interest in this because I can't get reverse-i-search (aka Ctrl +R) working under libedit in my rails console) Switching to readline might fix that

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a solution which worked for me.
First step, I installed GNU Readline like shown [here](https://noknow.info/it/os/install_readline_from_source). In my case I did:

```
wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/readline/readline-8.1.tar.gz
tar xvfz readline-8.1.tar.gz
cd readline-8.1
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/readline/8.1
make
make install

ln -s /usr/local/readline/8.1/include/readline /usr/local/include/

ln -s /usr/local/readline/8.1/lib/libhistory.a /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/readline/8.1/lib/libhistory.so /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/readline/8.1/lib/libhistory.so.8 /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/readline/8.1/lib/libhistory.so.8.1 /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/readline/8.1/lib/libreadline.a /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/readline/8.1/lib/libreadline.so /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/readline/8.1/lib/libreadline.so.8 /usr/local/lib/
ln -s /usr/local/readline/8.1/lib/libreadline.so.8.1 /usr/local/lib/
```

Then I reisntalled Ruby and compiled it with GNU readline, like discussed [here](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/1016):

```
rvm get head
rvm reinstall ruby --disable-binary --with-opt-dir=$(brew --prefix readline)
```

Finally when compiling my project I used -lcurses option (  `-lreadline -lcurses`) as discussed [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/2919).